# TypedJs bulk typing effect not working

Tags: javascript, html

I would make a bulk typing effect like [this example](https://mattboldt.com/typed.js/) at the end of the page

```
export class AProposComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('text', { read: ElementRef }) text: ElementRef
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let textEl = this.text.nativeElement
    let typed = new Typed(textEl, {
      strings: ['npm install...^1000<br> `installing components...` ^1000 <br> `Fetching from source...`'],
      typeSpeed: 40,
      backSpeed: 0,
      loop: true
    })
  }
}
```

I'm getting a normal typing effect ( like the first example )

```
npm install...
`installing components...`
`Fetching from source...`
```

How can I make bulk type effect using Typesjs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example should be working fine.

Use `\n` and css style `white-space: pre;` instead of `<br>` to avoid flickering effect.

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/rL4xsotx/), works same way for me as in typedjs examples

Comment: Thanks you, I have also updated my package.json to lastest typed.js, now it's working